# User's uSNChanged not updated when memberOf changes

Tags: active-directory

I'm trying to verify if this is an AD flaw. When a user is added to or removed from a group, the memberOf is updated BUT the user's uSNChanged does not change. I'm trying to detect changes in the groups the user belongs to.

Of course, I figured out that the group's uSNChanged changes when this happens. Comparing with past group state, I can in a roundabout way determine what I'm after.

But this seems needlessly complicated. Is there a better way to do this? Or is this an AD 'feature' that has to be lived with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears after much testing and research that the above is true and so it's a 'feature'. Oh well.

Comment: It's a 'computed' attribute (not even stored), so a user can't change it directly, only by modifying group. So, technically, it's expected behaviour. I'm also working on tracking AD changes to users and groups. What is the best way you've found so far?

Comment: It's as I described in my question above - if a group's uSNChanged is modified, then:
* capture the user list and update the server
* on the server, figure out deletions (any user on the server, but not in the updated list)
* on the server, figure out additions (any user NOT on the server, but in the updated list)

Not exactly elegant, but works.